# How to measure Network Utilization for NICs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, kql, azure-monitoring

Can anyone tell me if there is a query that exists in KQL that identifies network utilization for NICs in Azure?  I have tried to run queries that return only Bytes Received and Current Bandwidth but can't seem to find a way to calculate the actual Network Utilization such as the performance counters on Windows.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are four metrics that Azure Monitor provides [out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftnetworknetworkinterfaces) for network interfaces:

- Bytes Received: Number of bytes the Network Interface received
- Bytes Sent: Number of bytes the Network Interface sent
- Packets Received: Number of packets the Network Interface received
- Packets Sent: Number of packets the Network Interface sent

You can explore the following approaches for collecting additional Performance counters on Windows:

- With LA agents: [Collect Windows performance data sources with Log Analytics agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-performance-counters)
- With Application Insights: [System performance counters in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-counters)